# Vagrant - Django server - Why is host redirecting to https?

Tags: python, django, vagrant

I setup a vagrant VM with django installed, and setup the port forwarding like this:

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8001
```

So in the guest machine I run the django server like this:

```
python manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And the server starts up and tells me its running on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`
When I open up firefox on the host machine and point it to `http://127.0.0.1:8001`, it automatically redirects to `https://127.0.0.1:8001` and I get this error:

> An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:8001. SSL received
>   a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code:
>   SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Nowhere in the `settings.py` file does it force https. I don't know whats causing it to redirect to https, or how I can go about figuring that out. Is this a problem with virtualbox, vagrant or django?

These error messages appear in the terminal where I run the server:

```
[06/Jan/2017 05:17:22] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x00¥\x01\x00\x00¡\x03\x03d')
You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
[06/Jan/2017 05:17:31] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ("\x16\x03\x01\x00¥\x01\x00\x00¡\x03\x03É\x8aVY@¦Û2\x
9c'\x1a5n¬òðÿðªª®pÛ%å\x15#8jÕQé\x00\x00")
You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

So the question is why is my browser trying to access the server over HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this in your settings.py file :

```
 SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
```

For further reading, [Read from here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#secure-ssl-redirect)